# PhantomJS Crash - Exit Code 126

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, phantomjs, gruntjs

I'm getting a strange issue when trying to run phantomJS in my workflow on a CentOS (64bit) system.

Here is the error it's reporting:

```
[4mRunning "qunit:all" (qunit) task[24m Testing http://localhost:8000/tests.html 

Running PhantomJS...[31mERROR[39m
[31m>> [39m/home/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/nick_node_te/web-client/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /home/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/nick_node_te/web-client/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: cannot execute binary file 0 [ '/home/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/nick_node_te/web-client/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: /home/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/nick_node_te/web-client/client/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: cannot execute binary file' ]

[33mWarning: PhantomJS exited unexpectedly with exit code 126. Use --force to continue.[39m

[31mAborted due to warnings.[39m
```

I can't seem to find any good documentation on this type of crash. Is this usual and/or worthy of a bug report?

UPDATE:

These are the permissions on my file:

```
-rwxr-x--x. 1 root root 11308856 Sep 26 12:39 phantomjs
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like it's not built for the platform you're trying to run it on. Make sure to delete your `node_modules` directory and do a fresh `npm install` when you clone your repository to a fresh platform. It's currently bad practice to include your `node_nodules` dir in with your source control. Just keep your `package.json` file maintained well and do a `npm install` or `npm update` for each repo clone. Also, add `node_modules/` to your `.gitignore` file if you're using `git` so you don't have to worry about accidently including it when you add changes and commit.