# How to move npm node_modules folder cross-platform?

Tags: node.js, operating-system, continuous-integration, npm

I have a very special requirement from my client. We have been using npm to install karma and phantomjs for quite a while. Everything works fine until we have to move everything off the cloud to internal infrastructure. Now things get complicated. The internal infrastructure doesn't have internet access so we cannot use npm to resolve dependencies anymore. We tried to move node_modules folder dev machine to the internal infrastructure machine. It didn't work because dev machine is OSX and Windows and the server is Centos and phantomjs is OS specific but npm is able to workout the versioning. What options do we have to resolve dependencies? I just learn that node_modules name cannot be changed. I was thinking of checking in OS specific node_modules but that wouldn't work since npm only looks for node_modules folder.

I got the same error as this thread [PhantomJS Crash - Exit Code 126](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013918/phantomjs-crash-exit-code-126) when I was trying to use node_modules from OSX in Centos.

Comment: Why don't you install your project in a VM with this OS?

Comment: That's an option as well. But I just want to hear more from the community. Thanks for the suggestion by the way.

Comment: VM is not exactly a solution. I use docker and have the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Install all dependencies on first OS (i.e. OSX), assuming that you have package.json with all dependencies.

> npm install

Rename created npm_modules to **npm_modules_mac**

Repeat steps above for different OS (i.e. Windows), rename node_modules to something like **node_modules_windows**.

On target OS, move folders created above to your app folder, create symbolic link (node_modules), which will point to appropriate folder (npm_modules -> npm_modules_mac in OSX)

Comment: This will not allow you to run them in parallel because you can only one symlink.

Comment: can you kindly explain, how to create dynamic symbolic link?

Comment: sure, its `ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink` in mac/linux. in windows 10 you can use `mklink "path" "new path"`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just host your private registry? You can store the registry in the internal infrastructure.

The defacto registry is @isaacs own npmjs.org. This can be found here:

https://github.com/isaacs/npmjs.org

It does require using CouchDB as the database, however, and that can be daunting. There are alternatives that allow you to do this. For example, reggie:

https://github.com/mbrevoort/node-reggie